# JavaScript: function blur

Tags: javascript, blur

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <title>
         P&aacute;gina con Javascript.
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onClick="self.blur();">
         Desenfocar esta ventana
      </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

the function .blur() is the problem i been tried in differens browsers. Thank you.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: Can you rephrase as a question?

Comment: first of all, `.blur()` is a jQuery method so you have to link jQuery. now, if google translate is not wrong and **"Desenfocar esta ventana"** actually means **"blur this window"** then your code will need to be `$(window).blur()`. now, i have no idea why would you want to blur your window, so if you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, we might be able to assist you further.

Comment: Thank you... im reading a JavaScript book and it aply the blur() function for Javascript not JQuery. Then ... blur() is a JQuery function? it doesnt work whit Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, maybe, what you are trying to do?

```
<button onClick="this.blur();">
    Desenfocar esta ventana
</button>
```

Comment: Here is an example of an input wich start with de focus on it, but once you click it, it looses the focus. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dade3007/g4mnta70/1/)

Comment: Blur is a Javascript method, as you can see in the documentation -> [link](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_blur.asp)